# How to add elements to an arrayList everytime the timer tick in C#?

Tags: c#, arraylist, timer

I have a method which generates a random number every time the timer ticks (interval: 2s)

```
public static double RandomNumber(double min, double max)
{
  lock (synk)
  {
    return random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
  }
}
```

and I want to add values from the random method to an array list such as:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(RandomNumber(double min, double max))
double totalSum = Sum(list);
```

The `Sum()` method is:

```
private double Sum(ArrayList arr)
{
  double sum = 0;

  foreach (double i in arr)
  {
    sum = sum + i;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

but when I check the contents of the list (in a textBox), it is added every time only the last value. I can not add all values to the list. Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? You're creating the list every time, that's why it has only the last value

Comment: Also, don't use `ArrayList`. `List<double>` is superior in just about every way.

Comment: Do you really need the list at all? If you're just going to do the sum on each timer tick, just add the new value to a single `double` field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't seen the full code, the problem is that you're creating your `ArrayList` every time the timer calls your method. You should create the list outside your function, so that the values will be preserved.

Secondly, it's better to use `List<T>` as a list container as it's strongly-typed and has LINQ support for operations you need (unless you're using and old .NET version) (as pointed by [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho) may be you don't even need the whole list?).

Taking into consideration the above points your code should look like this:

```
private readonly List<double> _list = new List<double>(); 
//created and initialized outside of your function
public void CaylledByTimer()
{
   _list.Add(RandomNumber(min, max));
   double totalSum = _list.Sum(); //you can use built-in LINQ Sum function
}
```